# Wordpress remove_accents() not working when getting value from XML

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, import

I have special problem. I'm using WP All Import Pro plugin to import XML to Wordpress posts.

I need use WordPress function **remove_accents()** for strip Czech accents (ěščřžýáíé) for post slug.

If I set variable manually (ignore $mytitle), all works fine.

```
function seofriendly_slug($mytitle) {
    $finalslug = remove_accents("Test string ěščřžýáíé");
    return $finalslug;
}

OUTPUT: Test string escrzyaie
```

But if I use variable $mytitle that coming from XML (utf8):

```
[seofriendly_slug({PRACOVISTE[1]/@nazev})]
```

Variable is set propertly but remove_accents does not work:

```
function seofriendly_slug($mytitle) {
    $finalslug = remove_accents($mytitle);
    return $finalslug;
}

OUTPUT: Test string ěščřžýáíé
```

Last info: When I use mb_detect_encoding($mytitle), output is "ASCII" but in XML header is UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

I get solution from WorkScout theme creator - PureThemes.

```
html_entity_decode($prepareslug, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Final code:

```
function seofriendly_slug($nazev,$doplnek,$obec) {
    if ($doplnek ==NULL) { $titulek = $nazev; } 
        else { $titulek = $doplnek; }
    $prepareslug = $titulek."-".$obec;
    $prepareslug = html_entity_decode($prepareslug, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $finalslug = sanitize_title($prepareslug);
    return $finalslug;
}
```